# Is there a sqlldr api for java

Tags: java, oracle, sql-loader

I want to use **sqlldr** from a java program, but I dont want to invoke it using "Runtime.exec".
is there such api for **sqlldr** in java.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6057742/using-sqlldr-from-java

Comment: There is no programmatic API for sqlldr.  Use External Tables instead: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3661677/shell-script-to-find-filename-line-count-of-each-file-now-insert-this-record-i/3663254#3663254

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no native API to call SQL*Loader functionality from Java.

The only option you have is to use Runtime.exec() (or a ProcessBuilder).